# What chemical / solution / reagent are TSA agents using when they test liquids?

Tags: usa, health, airports, tsa

I was reading a news article that apparently TSA agents in the US have been randomly swabbing liquids including drinks, even purchased in the airport beyond the existing screening.

It was stated that the TSA claimed the tests were conducted using a "non-toxic solution".

But just what is the solution? How can I know it's safe? If I or someone in my care has allergies I need to know if this solution could invoke a reaction.

Is there a source which tells us what it is and what is in it? If so does it contain anything to which it is known some people have allergies?

Answer (score 7):

You will probably need to file a FOIA request to get that information.

Some chemicals can cause reactions and have not been tested for cancer.

TSA probably uses a product called ["Elite EL200" marketed by "Scanna MSC"](http://www.scanna-msc.com/Documentation_files/EL100-E%20-%20EL100%20and%20EL220%20-%20English.pdf) to test drinks.

Comment: Thanks Bill. But how do we know that TSA probably use this? It would be good to know where our hunches come from.

Comment: I would absolutely love to find out what is in this swab. I was just swabbed in Shreveport and had a major rash/reaction after the swab. Luckily I thought to take pics and will be trying to look into this more.